# Unable to copy binary file via c program

Tags: c, file, copy

I had made a program in c in Ubuntu using gcc-7.I had sambleb.out file which is executable.I want to copy that file using c programming. here is the program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("sampleb.out","rb");

    FILE *fpcp;
    fpcp = fopen("cp-of-sampleb.out","wb");

    char forcp;
    while (1)
    {
        forcp = fgetc(fp);
        if(forcp == EOF)
            break;
        fputc(forcp, fpcp);
    }

    fclose(fp);
    fclose(fpcp);
}
```

when I compile the program and execute the it, I get segmentation fault.

```
 $ a.out && chmod a+x cp-of-sampleb.out
 $ ./cp-of-sampleb.out
 Segmentation fault
```

here is the content of cp-of-sample.out

```
$ cat cp-of-sampleb.out 
ELF>0@@@@8  @@@@@@��88@8@@@,, `` ( 
((`(`��TT@T@DDP�td@@44Q�tdR�td``��/lib64/ld-
linux-x86-64.so.2GNU GNUX�T3�O���t�R�b�Ss�F
                                                  $ 
libc.so.6printf__libc_start_main__gmon_start__GLIBC_2.2.5ui 
3�`` `H�H�%
             H��t�CH��
```

and content of sampleb.out

```
$ cat sampleb.out 
ELF>0@@@@8  @@@@@@��88@8@@@,, `` ( 
((`(`��TT@T@DDP�td@@44Q�tdR�td``��/lib64/ld-
linux-x86-64.so.2GNU GNUX�T3�O���t�R�b�Ss�F
                                                  $ 
libc.so.6printf__libc_start_main__gmon_start__GLIBC_2.2.5ui 
3�`` `H�H�%
             H��t�CH���5
                          �%
                             @�%
                                 h������%

h������%�
]�8`��D]�fD�8`UH��8`H��H��H��H��?
H�H��t�H��tU�8`H=8`H��t�H��t
                                                ]�8`��]�fD�=a

uUH���~����O

]�D��@f.�UH��]��UH�忸@�������]�f.�DAWAVA��AUATL�% UH�- 
SI��I��L)�H�H���g���H��t 
1��L��L��D��A��H��H9�u�H�[]A\A]A^A_Ðf.���H�H��how are you I am 
fine this singale line is printed by multiline 
printf;4�����0���P����0��������zRx

�����*zRx

�$h���0FJ
U                                                                                         
�?;*3$"DW���A�C
Dd`���eB�B�E �B(�H0�H8�M@r8A0A(B BB�����@�@
�@` `���o�@@�@                                   �@
?
 `0�@�  ���o`@���o���oX@(`@@GCC: (Ubuntu 7.1.0-
5ubuntu2~16.04) 7.1.08@T@t@�@�@@X@`@    �@
�@
   �@
@0@�@�@@8@` `(`�``(`8`��
                                                       `@�@!
�@78`F `m@y`������(@���(`(���`�(`(8`8�08)8h�    P�
```

(I hadn't posted last line cause they were to many).Thus I can see that  my program is coping only first 7 lines.It will be very helpful if you tell me what is wrong??? I am still noob.

Comment: `char forcp;` ==> `int forcp;`. Function `fgetc` returns `int` so that in binary data you can distinguish `0xFF` data from `-1` EOF.

Comment: `chmode` is presumably a typo for `chmod`.  You don't test that the files were opened successfully; that's always *bad* — **very** ***bad!***

Comment: The [`fgetc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc) function returns an `int`. This is important for the `EOF` check.

Comment: As for your crash, I recommend you read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert, and learn how to use a debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, any such program should check the result of `fopen()` before continuing. If you don't do this, you're potentially using a `NULL` pointer that's returned from `fopen()` in case of failure and your program will crash.

Your immediate problem is that you assign the return value of `fgetc()` to a `char`. `fgetc()` returns an `int` which **either** corresponds to the value of an `unsigned char` **or** is `EOF`, an `int` constant that is *negative* and *distinct* from any valid character.

What might happen when you compare `EOF` to a `char` is the following: Your `char` can be signed, so in a binary file, you could find a byte that is `-1` with signed `char`. `-1` is often used as the `int` (!) value of `EOF`, so your comparison will be true even though `fgetc()` did **not** return `EOF`.

Fix: Replace `char forcp;` with `int forcp;`.

That all said, it's very inefficient copying a file *byte by byte*. You should better use a buffer and `fread()`/`fwrite()` for copying, like in the following example that also adds proper error checking:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define BUFFERSIZE 8192  // 8 kiB

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc != 3)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s source dest\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    FILE *src = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
    if (!src)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening %s for reading.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    FILE *dst = fopen(argv[2], "wb");
    if (!dst)
    {
        fclose(src);
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening %s for writing.\n", argv[2]);
        return 1;
    }

    char buf[BUFFERSIZE];
    int rc = 1; // <- failure
    do
    {
        size_t nread = fread(buf, 1, BUFFERSIZE, src);
        if (nread < BUFFERSIZE)
        {
            if (ferror(src))
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error reading from %s.\n", argv[1]);
                goto done;
            }
            if (!nread) break;
        }

        if (fwrite(buf, 1, nread, dst) < nread)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error writing to %s.\n", argv[2]);
            goto done;
        }
    } while (!feof(src));

    rc = 0; // <- success

done:
    fclose(dst);
    fclose(src);
    return rc;
}
```